# Secure web proxy (HTTPs) settings sending plain http request

Tags: proxy, http

I have my Secure web proxy (HTTPs) setting as following.
Server: my.proxy.net
Port: 5000

It looks like my proxy server gets a request, but gives error like this.
http: TLS handshake error from my.ip.address:port: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

I have no problem accessing the proxy server from Windows, so I'm not sure if it is client's (macos) problem or server's (proxy server) problem.